# Make tabs responsive on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following tabs and I would like to make them responsive when in smaller screens. Currently the last tabs just disappear when I make the screen smaller. The best scenario would be... when in smaller screens the tabs will start stacking below the first ones. Any ideas on how to implement this?

```js
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var toggle;
    return toggle = new Toggle('.toggle');
  });

  this.Toggle = (function() {
    Toggle.prototype.el = null;

    Toggle.prototype.tabs = null;

    Toggle.prototype.panels = null;

    function Toggle(toggleClass) {
      this.el = $(toggleClass);
      this.tabs = this.el.find(".tab");
      this.panels = this.el.find(".panel");
      this.bind();
    }

    Toggle.prototype.show = function(index) {
      var activePanel, activeTab;
      this.tabs.removeClass('active');
      activeTab = this.tabs.get(index);
      $(activeTab).addClass('active');
      this.panels.hide();
      activePanel = this.panels.get(index);
      return $(activePanel).show();
    };

    Toggle.prototype.bind = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return this.tabs.unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        return _this.show($(e.currentTarget).index());
      });
    };

    return Toggle;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

```css
.toggle {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.toggle .tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.toggle .tabs .tab {
  float: left;
  background: white;
  color: #777777;
  height: 31px;
  margin: 2px 8px 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .tabs .tab.active {
  color: #dd4b39;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dd4b39;
}
.toggle .panels .panel {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: none;
}
.toggle .panels .panel:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle'>
  <div class='tabs'>
    <div class='tab active'>Tab 1</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 2</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 3</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panels'>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 1</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 2</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 3</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle web-page responsiveness:

1.) Use `flex view` to make it scale based on the size of your page. But this doesn't sustain much because beyond a point the text starts to overflow the container.

2.) Use `media queries` to change the page layout at different sizes of the page. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: thanks for the reply @varun agarwal, I will try it out and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was very simple... I just had to delete the height from the following:

```
.toggle .tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 36px; ////////delete this here
  line-height: 36px;
}
```